# How can I generate /proc/vmcore?

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to practice with makedumpfile. However, it needs `/proc/vmcore` which is the memory image of the currently running kernel.

Also, reading the man page of `makedumpfile`, we also need 2 kernels: panicked kernel (crashed kernel) and capture kernel. Does this capture kernel run on the same machine or remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capture kernel runs on the same host.  It runs in memory that the panic'd kernel reserved for the capture kernel to use.  The capture kernel is started with the `kexec` mechanism by the panicing kernel.

`/proc/vmcore` should be provided by the kernel if its setup to export a memory image.  If your kernel does not have a `/proc/vmcore`, then you're missing the right kernel 
infrastructure.

The [linux kernel source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4.4/fs/proc/vmcore.c) implies that `/proc/vmcore` is only populated inside a capture kernel (the kernel command line providing the address of the panic'd kernels vmcore ELF header is required), so `/proc/vmcore` will exist in a regular kernel, but won't contain anything at all.

Inside the capture kernel, `/proc/vmcore` presents the crashed kernel as an [ELF core image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Here's some RH doc with more details: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/6038

Comment: Thanks. Our system uses SLES (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server), and it generates `vmcore`. I just want to know how it is generated in a standard way. But since you mention this is kernel specific, I will look into the specific documents.

Comment: From the source (linux/fs/proc/vmcore.c) looks like /proc/vmcore only contains something "interesting" inside the capture kernel.  In a regular kernel its empty.  When /proc/vmcore is valid, the data is presented in ELF "core" file format.